# SSL Handshake with Google Cloud Run Issued TLS Certificate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a Server Application Being Deployed on Google Cloud Run.
My Requirement is that, I want to establish a TLS handshake from the Server deployed on Cloud Run with an External Service and for that Reason I want the TLS Certificate from Cloud Run.
The Problem is that, If I want to make use Of my Self Signed Certificate as the TLS Certificate then the documentation says that we need to have a Global External HTTPS Load Balancer in front Of Cloud Run(which I do not want to do)

Hence I am following the Approach where I am Mapping a Custom Domain to my Cloud Run Service and then use the Google Managed TLS Certificate to perform the TLS Handshake.
Is there a way around how can I Accomplish this ?

Comment: Are you looking for [this document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#map)? If not, can you explain what you are exactly looking for?

Comment: @RoopaM I already have this document with me. I have mentioned my Requirements in the Question I want to make use of the Google Managed Certificate of Cloud Run to establish SSL handshake with a Service

Comment: Your usage of SSL/TLS terms is incorrect and confusing. Are you trying to connect from a Cloud Run application to another service? Are you also trying to use a self-signed certificate as client credentials (mTLS)? Or are you trying to connect from another service to your Cloud Run application? Why are you using self-signed certificates? Edit your post (not via comments) with more details on the connection and configuration scenario.